# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\frac{x dx}{\sin x +\cos x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I cant seem to work this out, can someone pls. help,

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\frac{x dx}{\sin x +\cos x}$$

You are meant to use the property of integral that:

$$\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx = \int_{0}^{a}f(a-x)dx$$

Comment: Have you tried using that property?

Comment: Yes, I did try, in fact I asked several of my teachers at my high school, but I get stuck when I reach integral of 1/sinx

Comment: If you show your steps then it would be a lot easier to identify where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $I = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x dx} {\cos x + \sin x}$. Then by using your identity we get,

\begin{align} I&= \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\pi/2-x}{\sin x+ \cos x} dx\\
2I&= \frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\sin x + \cos x} dx\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt 2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\sin x+\frac{1} {\sqrt2}\cos x} dx\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt 2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \csc(\pi/4+x) dx \tag{*}
\end{align}
On (*) we were using the fact that $\sin (x+y)=\sin x \cos y +\cos x \sin y$.

EDIT: Now that I think about it the last integral is a little tricky. But we can use the following famous trick to evaluate it. $ \int \csc u du =\int \csc u \frac{\csc u-\cot u}{\csc u-\cot u} du=\ln \vert \csc u-\cot u \vert+C$.Notice that $\ln \vert \csc u-\cot u \vert$ is an antiderivative of the integrand because the derivative of $\ln \vert \csc u-\cot u \vert$ is precisely the integrand. You can evaluate your integral from here. Or you can use a bit of trig to show that $\ln \vert \csc u-\cot u \vert= \ln \lvert \tan(u/2) \rvert$. This probably makes evaluating the integral a little less painful. :).

Comment: Yep I got up to that, but what is the integral of csc(x) ?

Comment: @GeniusAsis If you know how to integrate $\sec(x)$, then you can change coordinates to $u=\pi/2-x$ to turn the integral involving $\csc(x)$ to one involving $\sec(u)$.

Comment: yep.... that makes a lot more sense! Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{x\,\dd x \over \sin\pars{x} +\cos\pars{x}}}
\\[3mm]&=\half\bracks{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{x\,\dd x \over \sin\pars{x} +\cos\pars{x}}
+\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\pars{\pi/2 - x}\,\dd x\over
\sin\pars{\pi/2 - x} +\cos\pars{\pi/2 - x}}}
\\[3mm]&={\pi \over 4}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\dd x \over \sin\pars{x} +\cos\pars{x}}
={\pi \over 4}\int_{0}^{1}{2\,\dd x/\pars{1 + x^{2}}\over
2x/\pars{1 + x^{2}} + \pars{1 - x^{2}}/\pars{1 + x^{2}}}\qquad\qquad\pars{1}
\\[3mm]&=-\,{\pi \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over x^{2} - 2x - 1}
=-\,{\pi \over 2}\int_{-1}^{0}{\dd x \over x^{2} - 2}
\\[3mm]&=-\,{\pi \over 2}\,{1 \over 2\root{2}}\int_{0}^{1}
\pars{{1 \over x - \root{2}} - {1 \over x + \root{2}}}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=-\,{\root{2}\pi \over 8}
\ln\pars{\verts{{1 - \root{2} \over 1 + \root{2}}\,{\root{2} \over -\root{2}}}}
=\color{#66f}{\large -\,{\root{2} \over 8}\,\ln\pars{3 - 2\root{2}}\pi}
\approx 0.9790
\end{align}

> In $\pars{1}$ we used [Weierstrass Substitution or/and Tangent Half-Angle Substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution).